# ASP.net client ID mode

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config

I've got this line in my web.config:

```
<pages validateRequest="false" smartNavigation="false" clientIDMode="Static">
```

This was working fine, the Id's I assigned to the controls came out as they were in code.  However, for some reason on the live server they have all started rendering with the server generated names such as:

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$Password2" type="password" maxlength="32" id="Password2" class="nice-textbox" />
```

Anyone know what could be causing them to render this way?  It's causing a lot of pages to break.

I'm trying to find the setting via IIS to make sure it's loading it correctly but can't find it.

Comment: `clientIDMode` is new in .NET 4. So is your live server's application pool not running 4.0?

Comment: @Tim yes, will check it all now though.  It was all working fine until about 2 days ago.  2 days ago I did install some server monitoring software which I'm removing now and rebooting the server to see if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

[`clientIDMode`](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Nov/07/ClientIDMode-in-ASPNET-40) is new in .NET 4. Is your live server's application pool not running 4.0?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754523%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

1. Open IIS Manager. For information about opening IIS Manager, see Open IIS Manager (IIS 7).
2. On the Connections pane, expand the server node and click Application Pools.
3. On the Application Pools page, select the application pool for which you want to specify a .NET Framework version, and then click Basic Settings in the Actions pane.
4. In the Edit Application Pool dialog box, in the .NET Framework version list, select the version that you want the application pool to use or select No Managed Code if the application uses only native code.
5. Click OK.

[image]

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for these instructions they are great.  I've fixed the issue.  2 days ago we installed NewRelic which is a monitoring service.  I uninstalled it and rebooted the server and it's now rendering the form controls with static ID's.  I've sent an email off to NewRelic to let them know, and I'm not 100% certain NewRelic was the cause but it's all working now.